# NodeJS: How to add routes afterwards (after middleware)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware

i'm currently working on a project with node.js.
I stucked at a specific problem. After adding all routes
with express (app.get("..", func)) I end up with a middleware that 
catches all requests and redirects to a 404-page.

The thing is now, when I add a route afterwards during server run, the middleware
doesent care about the new route.

example:

```
app.get("/home", function(_, res) {
    res.send("home");
})

app.get("/faq", function(_, res) {
    res.send("faq");
})

app.use(function(_, res) {
    res.send("404");
});

// e.g. 10 min later..

app.get("/team", function(_, res) {
    res.send("team");
})
```

So i can access /home and /faq but after 10 min requesting the page /team, i am redirected to the 404 page.

**Does anybody know a solution ?  Im quite new to nodejs..**

Comment: From your wording it sounds like you might not have tried restarting the node/express process?

Comment: It's very likely that the route you are adding is being added *after* your 404 handler, so it never gets reached because anything that reaches the 404 handler receives a 404.

Comment: Your app.use code will send a 404 response, so all code afterwards will not be executet. Just leave app.get("/team", function(_, res) {
    res.send("team");
}) at the end of your code and everything will be fine

Answer (score 0):

Although adding routes dynamically doesn't sound like a good idea, here's a workaround: add an (empty) `Router` instance right before the 404 handler, and add the new routes to that router instead of to `app`:

```
let router = express.Router();
app.use(router);

app.use(function(_, res) {
    res.send("404");
});

// e.g. 10 min later..
router.get("/team", function(_, res) {
    res.send("team");
})
```

Comment: i need to add routes dynamically because of a lobbysystem (ex: /lobby/xsfr). Thank you very much!

Comment: @reByte sounds like what you actually need is a `/lobby` route that accepts a param, not additional routes. for example, `/lobby/:id`

Comment: Yes, I agree with @KevinB on that.